# InvalidOperationException Occurred in Linq orderby clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, invalidoperationexception

Here is the linq statement I am using:

```
var sortedList =
        (from p in OriginalList
         where p.NValue != null
         orderby Math.Abs(p.NValue.Value) descending
         select p);
```

OriginalList is a list of Transaction objects with more than 10 thousand elements. NValue is nullable property of Transaction. Every time OriginalList is updated, the statement will be executed.

I have found that from time to time, this statement could throw the following exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

I tried to do unit testing and fed it with an OriginalList with only one Transaction. This Transaction has null NValue. It won't trigger this exception.

Anyone has idea what is going on here? Thanks a lot.

We are using Linq to SQL. Here is the stack trace:

2011-10-05 16:14:06,826 [SRV101 DC\Admin] [59] ERROR Utils.AProxy`1 - AProxy [TProxy] error during load

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

at CServer.TLoader.b__2(Trasaction p) in c:\...\TLoader.cs:line 61
at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__0.MoveNext()
at CServer.TLoader.GetMultipliers(IEnumerable`1 OriginalList) in c:\...\TLoader.cs:line 64
at CServer.TProxy.OnLoad() in c:\...\TProxy.cs:line 29
at Utils.AProxy`1.Load() in c:\...\AProxy.cs:line 252
```

Comment: Please tell us what sort of LINQ you're using - what is the exact type of `OriginalList`, and are you using LINQ to SQL, LINQ to NHibernate etc?

Comment: And a stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: What happened to digEmAll's answer? I definitely saw that it was correct.

Comment: @invisible he deleted it because he missed the `where p.NValue!=null` clause.

Comment: Maybe there is some issue with nullable types? Try using `p.NValue.HasValue` instead of comparing p.NValue to null. I'm sure should be the same, but maybe not in this context.

Comment: Quacks like a threading bug.  Another thread changing the NValues while the query is being enumerated.

Comment: @HansPassant - I'm starting to think the same thing, in singular linear execution I can't replicate at all.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing seems to indicate that you are trying to evalute .Value on a Null. Try using .GetValueOrDefault instead, otherwise change your where clause to check for HasValue rater than just comparing against null:

```
var sortedList h= 
        (from p in OriginalList 
         where p.NValue.HasValue 
         orderby Math.Abs(p.NValue.Value) descending 
         select p);
```

In your case p.NValue = Nullable thus p.NValue == null evalues to True, but p.NValue.HasValue == false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Math.Abs is supported in Linq-to-Sql, so you can do something like this

```
var sortedList =
        (from p in OriginalList
         where p.NValue != null
         orderby p.NValue.Value < 0 ? (p.NValue.Value * -1) : p.NValue.Value descending
         select p);
```